# Using Fetch to put JSON in body of document - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I am trying to send JSON back to my express app with a POST method using fetch(). Here is my code:

```
 fetch('https://development.c9users.io/canadmin',{
                method:'POST',
                body:JSON.stringify({
                    csv: results
                })
```

Here is my post method in Express:

```
app.post("/canadmin", function(req,res){
var data = req.body.csv;
console.log(data);
//  r.db('cansliming').table('daily').insert( r.json(data) ).run(err, );
res.redirect("canadmin");
});
```

I get undefined through my console.log so I am unsure if I am getting my data correctly. What am I missing here? Is my fetch - body incorrect? That is what my guess is however I cannot figure out the correct syntax.

//***********EDIT-SOLUTION************//

I went to a Javascript meetup and a nice guy named Alex found the solution. The header was incorrect, we also added the mode:

```
fetch('/saveRecords',{
                headers: {
                        //This is the line we need for sending this data
                      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
                },
                mode : 'no-cors',
                method:'POST',
                //This is the line we need actually send the JSON data
                body: JSON.stringify(results)
             }) //End fetch()
```

After doing this I was able to see it in my req.body in Express! I hope this helps someone.

Comment: console.log(req.body)

Comment: I did that and it just gave { }

Comment: Is any specific reason, you are converting body in `String` during request time?

Answer (score 2):

slightly different solution worked for me. body-parser [does not handle `multipart/form-data` bodies](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

client side `fetch` call sends data to express:

```
fetch('api/users', {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, // tells the server we have json
  method:'PUT', // can be POST
  body: JSON.stringify(results), // json is sent to the server as text
})
```

server side express `app` listens for `application/json` and parses it to json:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

After setting up the `bodyParser` I defined an express middleware function

```
app.put('/api/:collection', (req, res) => {
  logger.log('put', req.body)
  // ...
})
```

the `req.body` is json.

Comment: consider `headers = new Headers({'Content...:'application/json', ...other headers...})` I had trouble with this, the specific reasons I didn't take time to figure out, but was able to pass the existing headers property to the constructor and overwrite the original with success (into the api)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you're going to have to read from the `req` like a stream.  Something like this:

```
var body = '';
req.on('data', function (chunk) {
  body += chunk;
});

req.on('end', function () {
  console.log(JSON.parse(body));
});
```

A better solution is to use the [body-parser middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions).

Comment: I actually have bodyParser but I didnt think to use it for this. How would I do that in bodyParser?

Comment: @illcrx I linked to the instructions.  `app.use(bodyParser.json())`.

Comment: @illcrx If the code I just gave you isn't working, you should post a new question.

Comment: I thought the answer should match the question, not the other way around. Why would I repost the same question?

Comment: @illcrx You now have a different question.  You started out by asking how to handle a POST body with Express.  Now you're asking how to use the body-parser middleware, and the code I gave you in the comment and in the documentation isn't working for you.  That's a completely different question, with different code to show.

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to use body-parser middleware for post method.

for example pseudocode: (in ES6 format)

including body-parser:

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
const urlEncode = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});
```

now, use that on api post request like this:

```
app.post('/something_url', urlEncode, (req, res) => { ...your code here...});
```

Comment: Question I am using something similar, I have this:.........

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");......................app.post("/canadmin", bodyParser, function(req,res){
    var data = req.body;
    console.log(data);
  //  r.db('cansliming').table('daily').insert( r.json(data) ).run(err, );
    res.redirect("canadmin");
});